# Add/Remove Products to Compare with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add "product compare feature" in my website product list. I am wondering how can I make a Query String URL from product list page using jQuery. Looks like below one.

I need compare URL should be generated like below, and maximum product can be added as 4.

```
<a href="Compare.html?P1=123&P2=124&P3=125&P4=126">Compare Products</a>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/taxjD/341/

I can handle these query string parameter on `compare.html` page.

```
<div id="container" class="hidden">
    <p>There are 0 boxes</p>  
    **<a href="\compare.html?P1=123&P2=124&P3=125&P4=126">Compare</a>**
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <h1>Product Name 1</h1>
        <a href="#" class="more"> + Add to compare</a>
        <span class="ProdId">123</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Product Name 2</h1>
        <a href="#" class="more"> + Add to compare</a>
        <span class="ProdId">124</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Product Name 3</h1>
        <a href="#" class="more"> + Add to compare</a>
        <span class="ProdId">125</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".more").click(function() {
    var id=$(this).next('.ProdId').html();
    $("#container").append("<div class='box'> "+ id + "<a href='#'>x</a></div>");
    var count = $(".box").length;
    $("p").text("There are " + count + " boxes.");
    $("#container").removeClass("hidden");
});

$(".box a").live("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var count = $(".box").length;
    $("p").text("There are " + count + " boxes.");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to somehow keep track of the items that have been selected. That could be an array variable that you updated both on add and remove, but it could also be indicated in the `.box` elements you're creating. If you wrap the product ID in a span in the `.box` elements as well, you'll have an easier time targeting the ID:

```
$('<div/>', { 'class': 'box' })
   .append($('<span/>', { class: 'prod-id', text: id }))
   .append($('<a/>', { href: '#', text: 'x' }))
   .appendTo('#container');
```

You could then do:

```
var ids = $('.box .prod-id')
             .map(function(i, x) { return ['P', ++i, '=', $(this).text()].join(''); })
             .toArray();

$('#container > a').attr('href', 'Compare.html?' + ids.join('&'));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DET9R/)

**Update:**

Your additional requests are easily fulfilled now that we've established a way of retreiving the added products' IDs. Since we'll be reusing it, I've extracted `getSelectedIds` as a function of its own.

Now we just need to check its `length` to test the max 4 requirement, and its `indexOf(id)` to test whether the item was already added. If so, the code will just exit the `.more` click listener. You could show the user an error message at that point.

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DBfKz/)

Comment: David, Can you please put this example on Fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that jQuery's own `.map` doesn't return a regular array, so you have to `.toArray()` it for it to work. See fiddle and updated code in answer.

Comment: Thanks David, I saw this and working fine. One more little help required is. I want MAX 4 product can be added only and duplicate can not be added.

Comment: Hey David, Can you please suggest to set MAX 4 product can be added only and duplicate can not be added?

Comment: David, Can you please suggest me why remove button not working with jquery 2.0.2 . See here : http://jsfiddle.net/DBfKz/10/

Comment: `.live` has been removed from the framework. Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: David, would you like to see one more question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841196/hide-show-table-rows-based-on-checkbox-and-data-element , since nobody answered on this with proper code as you here.