# Save Add/Remove Products to Compare with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

How to save selected items on this script to be avilable after refresh or change page? 
(in answer; JSFiddle demo): [Add/Remove Products to Compare with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610967/add-remove-products-to-compare-with-jquery)

Edit:

1. What would be better practice cookies vs session?
2. I tried with cookies. I save all added items (id and image) to one cookie, and I manage only to delete all selected. How can I delete only one item from cookie?

Code:

```
 $("#compareContainerFill").append($.cookie("newLi"));

$(".compare").click(function() {

    var id=$(this).find('#compareID').text(); 

    var image=$(this).find('#imageURL').text();

    var selected = getSelectedIds();
    if(selected.length == 4) return; // already 4 items added
    if(selected.indexOf(id) != -1) return; // item already added

    var newLi = $('<div/>', { 'class': 'box' })
       .append($('<input type="hidden" value="'+id+'" name="compare_id['+id+']"/>'))
       .append($('<span/>', { class: 'prod-id hidden', text: id }))
       .append($('<a/>', { href: '#', text: '' }).append($('<img src="http://localhost/...imagelink">')))
       .appendTo('#compareContainerFill');

    $.cookie('newLi', (($.cookie("newLi") ? $.cookie("newLi") : '') + newLi.clone().wrap('<div />').parent().html()), { expires: 1 });


});

$("#compareContainerFill").live("click", function() {
    $.removeCookie('newLi');
    $('.box').remove();
});
```

Comment: Store a list of selected items in a cookie, and when the page is loaded, check the value of the cookie and set the correct objects to selected.

Answer (score 0):

Session variable, Localstorage, Cookies. You have a lot of options here